# Guestbook issues: Selecting table inside mySQL database + php tag wont close

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to select the table gaestebog inside the database akron11_db, and i dont know what the command is, the table has 3 values, id, bruger, and besked (id,user,message).
Second problem is that the `<?php` tag at the bottom wont close after the table is created.
I'm using notepad++ so i can see the tag is not closed due to the color coding.
Thanks in advance, i hope to one day be the guru in here that can help all you others.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <?php

        $sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "USER", "PW") or die(mysql_error);

        mysql_select_db("akron11_db", $sql);
        if($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
        {
        $bruger = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST)['bruger']);
        $besked = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['besked']);

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (bruger,besked) VALUES ('$bruger, $besked)");
        echo ("Tak for beskeden")
        }
    ?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        User: <input type="text" name="bruger"/><br />
        Message <textarea name="besked"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="post!"/>
        </form>


        <?php
            $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM besked ORDER BY id DESC");
            //DESC er decending
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));   
        {


        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruger:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bruger'] ?></td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Besked:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['besked'] ?></td>           
            </tr>

        </table>
        <hr />
        }
        ?>

    </html>
```

Comment: Question is, how do i select the table inside my database to write and later post the data into my table. And why wont the tag in the end close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php
        $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM besked ORDER BY id DESC");
        //DESC er decending
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));   
    {


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruger:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['bruger'] ?></td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Besked:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['besked'] ?></td>           
        </tr>

    </table>
    <hr />
    }
    ?>
```

You need opening and closing PHP tags around the HTML snippet:

```
   <?php
        $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM besked ORDER BY id DESC");
        //DESC er decending
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));   
    {
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruger:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['bruger'] ?></td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Besked:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['besked'] ?></td>           
        </tr>

    </table>
    <hr />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the tag problem. How do i select the table (gaestebog) from the database (akron11_db) as the source for the posting and query commands?

Comment: @Snigern `SELECT * FROM gaestebog` selects all the columns and all the rows in the `gaestebog` table.

Comment: I just corrected it thanks, ran it a few times after uploading and nothing gets written to the table.

Comment: @Snigern To insert is: `INSERT INTO gaestebog (user, message) ('$user', '$message')`.

Comment: Alot of small mistakes here. I have corrected all you have said so far, but it still seems like there is no connection to the table, nothing gets written or recieved. I have tested the acces to the db through another script and it is working.